# Push Notifications for multiple activity

Tags: java, android

I will let my notifications be for many Activity I do not know how to go about it either by or start but I have been able to find out how to get notifications for messages. is it possible to use it to have the notifications of others? if so please help me

```
 package com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications;

    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.Preference;


    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

    import com.developer.fireone.finga.MessageActivity;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

    import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

    /**
     * Created by user on 13/02/2019.
     */

    public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String sented = remoteMessage.getData().get("sented");
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String currentUser= preferences.getString("currentuser","none");


        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if(firebaseUser!=null && sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
            if(!currentUser.equals(user)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage);
                } else {
                    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
                }

            }
        }


    }

    private void sendOreoNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,j,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        OreoNotification oreoNotification = new OreoNotification(this);
        Notification.Builder builder = oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(title, body, pendingIntent,
                defaultSound, icon);

        int i = 0;
        if(j>0){
            i=j;
        }

        oreoNotification.getManager().notify(i, builder.build());


    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,j,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int i = 0;
        if(j>0){
            i=j;
        }

        noti.notify(i, builder.build());


    }
}
```

CommentActivity (please I want an exple with Commentactivity)

```
package com.developer.fireone.finga;

import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Adapter.CommentAdapter;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Fragment.APIService;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Model.Comment;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Model.User;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications.Client;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications.Data;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications.MyResponse;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications.Sender;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications.Token;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class CommentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CommentAdapter commentAdapter;
    private List<Comment> commentList;

    EditText addcomment;
    ImageView image_profile;
    TextView post;

    String postid;
    String publisherid, currentDate, currentTime;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    Intent intent;

    APIService apiService;
    boolean notify = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.comments1);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        //apiservice
        apiService = Client.getClient("https://fcm.googleapis.com/").create(APIService.class);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        postid = intent.getStringExtra("postid");
        publisherid = intent.getStringExtra("publisherid");


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        commentList = new ArrayList<>();
        commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, commentList, postid);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(commentAdapter);

        addcomment = findViewById(R.id.add_comment);
        image_profile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        post = findViewById(R.id.post);


        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                notify=true;
                if(addcomment.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, R.string.pasdecommentvide, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    addComment();
                }
            }
        });

        getImage();
        readComments();

    }

    private void addComment() {

        Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        currentDate = currentDateFormat.format(calForDate.getTime());

        Calendar calForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        currentTime = currentTimeFormat.format(calForTime.getTime());

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(postid);

        String commentid = reference.push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("comment", addcomment.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("publisher", firebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("commentid", commentid);
        hashMap.put("date", currentDate);
        hashMap.put("time", currentTime);

        reference.child(commentid).setValue(hashMap);
        addNotifications();
        addcomment.setText("");

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user =dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if(notify) {
                    sendNotificaion(firebaseUser.getUid(), user.getUsername(), addcomment.getText().toString());//here is what i try to follow it does not work
                }
                notify=false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    //here is what i try to follow it does not work
    private void sendNotificaion(String receiver, final String username, final String msg) {

        DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
        Query query = tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(receiver);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Token token = snapshot.getValue(Token.class);
                    Data data = new Data(firebaseUser.getUid(), R.mipmap.logo4, username+": "+msg, "New Comment", postid );

                    Sender sender = new Sender(data, token.getToken());

                    apiService.sendNotification(sender)
                            .enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                                    if(response.code()==200){
                                        if(response.body().success!=1){
                                            Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, R.string.failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void addNotifications(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(publisherid);

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("userid", firebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("text", getString(R.string.commenterxa)+" "+addcomment.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
        hashMap.put("ispost", true);
        hashMap.put("isseen", false);

        reference.push().setValue(hashMap);
    }


    private void getImage(){

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.keepSynced(true);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                final User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void readComments(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(postid);
        reference.keepSynced(true);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                commentList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Comment comment = snapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                    commentList.add(comment);
                }

                commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment

```
package com.developer.fireone.finga.Model;

/**
 * Created by user on 13/12/2018.
 */

public class Comment {

    private String comment;
    private String publisher;
    private String commentid;
    private  String date;
    private  String time;

    public Comment() {
    }

    public Comment(String comment, String publisher, String commentid, String date, String time) {
        this.comment = comment;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.commentid = commentid;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getCommentid() {
        return commentid;
    }

    public void setCommentid(String commentid) {
        this.commentid = commentid;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand exactly what you need

Comment: sorry if I explain myself badly, in short I want that when you comment on a user's post or when he receives an invitation from friends, he has a notification for everyone, I have done it for the messages and x works well and if it is possible to use this to make notifications for others . please help me...